How to input .mkv video files in one folder to ffmpeg and convert them to .mp4 and put the results in a different folder
I have a series of .mkv video files in one folder and I want to use ffmpeg to convert them to .mp4 and put the results in a different folder.
This is my attempt - which doesn't work:
cd ~/private/tv/017;
inpath = "~/private/rtorrent/data/";
for file in *.mkv; do ffmpeg -threads 1 -i $inpath$file -map 0 -c:v copy -c:a aac -c:s mov_text -movflags +faststart ${file/%mkv/mp4}; done

The parts that might be causing the trouble are $inpath$file and ${file/%mkv/mp4}.
Are these expressions valid or is something else wrong?

Unix or Windows? Please [edit] the question tags.

Assuming Bash, there's definetly an issue with the assignment (which is likely causing the problem), and a further potential issue with the the unquoted expansions.
The expression:
inpath = "~/private/rtorrent/data/";

Should rather be:
inpath=~/private/rtorrent/data/;

Because:

The spaces around the equal sign are making Bash interpretet inpath as a command instead of as an assignment;
The quotes around ~/private/rtorrent/data/ are preventing ~ from expanding to your home directory's path.

Adding to that, if a filename contained a character included in IFS (notably a space), both the unquoted expansions would make the command break.
cd ~/private/tv/017;
inpath=~/private/rtorrent/data/;
for file in *.mkv; do ffmpeg -threads 1 -i "$inpath$file" -map 0 -c:v copy -c:a aac -c:s mov_text -movflags +faststart "${file/%mkv/mp4}"; done

is the bare minimum to make the thing work safely. Personally, I would also drop the optional semicolons and wrap the variable names in the first expansion in {}, even though in this case that doesn't really matter (it'd help with avoiding breakages in case you happened to make changes to the path):
cd ~/private/tv/017
inpath=~/private/rtorrent/data/
for file in *.mkv; do ffmpeg -threads 1 -i "${inpath}${file}" -map 0 -c:v copy -c:a aac -c:s mov_text -movflags +faststart "${file/%mkv/mp4}"; done

